# How to search JodaDate And JodaTime using criteria?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new to grails.I'm using joda plugin for date and time.So i'm displaying date and time in separate column.Now i want to  search date using criteria.
I  used below code in gsp page to search  date.

```
<tr class="prop">
                                <td valign="top" class="name">
                                    <label for="createdOn"><g:message code="asset.createdOn.label" default="Created On" /></label>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: assetInstance, field: 'createdOn', 'errors')}">
                                    <joda:datePicker name="createdOn" precision="date" value="${assetInstance?.createdOn}" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

i used below code in controller by using criteria.

```
def search= {
     if (request.method == 'POST'){
     def criteria = Asset.createCriteria()

          def results = criteria { 

   or {
             gt('createdOn','%' + params.createdOn + '%').toDate()
             }


          }
         render(view:'list', model:[ assetInstanceList: results,assetInstanceTotal: Asset.count() ])
     }
       }
```

But it showing error.please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: It would help if you provided information about the error that's occurring.

Comment: Also, it makes me cringe when I see and use searches that `POST` instead of `GET`. Consider using `GET`. That way search results can be refreshed with the browser (e.g. with F5) without getting the "resubmit form data" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to bind your search to a command so that you have an actual bound Date object instead of a String parameter.

```
class SearchCommand {
    LocalDate createdOn
    ...
}
```

You'll also need to fix your criteria.

```
def search = { SearchCommand command ->
    ...

    def results = criteria {
        or {
            gt('createdOn', command.createdOn)
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. This is exactly what I was looking for.Your code helped me a lot.